# Function makes my window stop responding. I have no clue how to fix this :/

Tags: python, pygame

one of my functions is an intro to a very basic game that I am making in `pygame`.

The problem is that my function makes the window unresponsive while the function is being executed and I have no idea how to fix it.

I am a beginner when it comes to Python and pygame.

This is the code for the `intro` function:

```
def intro():
    message_display1("Text A")
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    gameDisplay.fill(color)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    message_display1("Text B")
    pygame.display.update()
    gameDisplay.fill(color)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    message_display1("Text C")
    pygame.display.update()
    gameDisplay.fill(color)
    pygame.display.update()
```

This is the `message_display1` function:

```
def message_display1(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',45)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

This is the `text_objects` function:

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Each time.sleep is pausing the thing for 2 seconds, so it is held up for a total of 6 seconds.  How do you want it to work?

Comment: it works techinically but if i do anything in the window (eg click) or to the window (eg moving it to the center of my screen) it stops responding and crashes but it doesn't give me an error so i'm at a complete loss of what to do. ps those time.sleeps are meant to be there so the player has time to read the text before the next text comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if I can take a shot at this.

First things first how about we trying some of this coding in try...except clauses and using the most generic exception possible.
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Two adding some nice and fancy python logging.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Now those two suggestions aside, I believe it is important to note what version of python you are using and complete context of the code with a concrete layout of your thought process. Lets face it we are not mind readers and it would be best to see a bit more code here in a coherent manner.

That being said, good job on your first step on getting started with programming a game in python and don't give up. It's all about failing fast and learning from your mistakes so that you can one day succeed!

Thanks,

-Abe.